# Eclipse: "Output exceeds cutoff limit" in scala worksheet

Tags: eclipse, scala

How can I grow the number of output lines in Eclipse, such that I do not receive any more this message in scala worksheet:

```
Output exceeds cutoff limit.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In eclipse preferences there is a menu item for `Scala Worksheet`

The option is only option `Maximum number of output characters to be shown after evaluation`. Set this to be higher than the default.

While this isn't the number of lines, its the only option.

Comment: Where can I find this preference ?

Comment: Well, I'm on mac, so I go to Eclipse > Preferences > Scala Worksheet. It is possibly in a different location on other OS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this answer. In trying it I found that in the current version of Eclipse/Scala Preferences has a Scala Worksheet menu item that lets you set the number of characters output for each statement before cutoff.